# Sum of total hours in sql

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I've a small issue while calculating sum of total hours

my working hours like

```
Day1 - 12.23 Hours
Day2 - 11.43 Hours
Day3 - 10.18 Hours
```

and when I calculate the sum it is showing 33.84

But actual result is 34.24. How can I get it by SQL query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show your code..

Comment: Actually I'm pulling data from table like select workinghours from emp. Now I want to add summary at the end. Hope you got it

Comment: Umm, that adds up to 33.84....

Comment: @jestges: you need to put more work into the question. Explain what you are trying to achieve and what you have attempted so far. I see in your comment below that you are asking about Crystal reports but there is no mention of this in your question. How do you expect anyone to be able to help you?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
;with hours as
(
select 12.53 as hours union all select 11.43 union all select 10.58
--select 12.23  as hours union all select 11.43 union all select 10.18 
)
,hours2 AS
(
select
floor(hours)  as rounded_hrs
,(hours % 1) * 100 as mins
FROM hours
)
SELECT 
CAST(sum(rounded_hrs) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) +
CAST(FLOOR(sum(mins) / 60) AS DECIMAL(18,2))  +
CAST((sum(mins) % 60) / 100 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
from hours2
```

Comment: Try your solution on this dataset instead: `select 12.53  as hours union all select 11.43 union all select 10.58`. It will not correct the result of `SUM(hours)` (which is `34.54` even though the correct result should be `35.54`).

Comment: @Andriy M - good spot - have edited and I think it should do the trick now, even if it's not the nicest looking thing!

Comment: I really like your `hours % 1` trick to strip the whole part of the number.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a query fr summing hours would be like:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_date_field))/3600 AS total_hours FROM yourTable
GROUP BY date(your_date_field), user_id;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: already I got all values and trying to bind it to crystal report. In crystal report summary it is showing wrong values. It is treating as decimal value rather than hours.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your hours are in fact values with whole parts as hours and fractions as minutes. In that case you'll have to sum whole parts and fraction parts separately:

```
WITH TimePartsSplit AS (
  SELECT
    IntHours = CAST(hours AS int),
    IntMinutes = CAST((hours - FLOOR(hours)) * 100 AS int)
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  SUM(IntHours), SUM(IntMinutes) / 60, SUM(IntMinutes) % 60 * 0.01,
  SUM(IntHours) + SUM(IntMinutes) / 60 + SUM(IntMinutes) % 60 * 0.01
FROM TimePartsSplit
```